# Exclude maven module from emma code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, maven, maven-2, code-coverage, emma

I have a maven super pom, consisting of multiple modules. I run `mvn emma:emma` on the super pom, and I get emma code coverage for all the modules (that have tests defined.)

Now I wish to exclude one of the modules from the emma code coverage run. Such that when I run  `mvn emma:emma` on the super pom, the specific module does not get code coverage measured. But when I do `mvn test` all module tests will be executed as normally.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in Maven Emma plugin docs, there's not such property to exclude some projects (modules) from coverage measurement. It seems that all reactor projects will be handled by Emma plugin.

What can be useful in your case is the plugin's [ability](http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/properties.html) to exclude some test classes (`maven.emma.filter.excludes` property) from coverage report, but it would work only of you're able to specify masks that catch test classes of modules' you want to effectively exclude, so it might not work in your case.